# What exception do we get upon low RAM in memory?

Tags: c#

If I am doing a recursive algorithm to traverse a tree...and I know it has a lot of data, huge..and after like 20 minutes I get a "Stack Overflow" exception. But StackOverFlow might be because of some other error in code , maybe because of an infinite-loop ... so I am just trying to make sure this SOF error I get in VisualStudio is because my recursive algorithm is running out of RAM and not because of other errors...Do we have a special type of error message or exception when we are running out of memory in a recursive algorithm at all?

Comment: StackOverflow never happens when you run out of RAM.  It happens when you have too many nested function calls.

Comment: _Do we have a special type of error exception_ Yes, StackOverFlowException...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I can't decide if that's a pun on the name of the site or an incorrect comment..hmm

Comment: @SLaks : " too many nested function calls." ... Yes it is a very very deep tree..and I am using Recursion to navigate the tree, so you think this can be the reason?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - The OP could be running of of Stack-memory... That's memory too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Obviously. But I'm pretty sure when he said "running out of memory" he was referring to all RAM, not just the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) can be thrown when memory is low. [System.StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) is that you've busted the call stack with something recursively ultra-complex or without a terminating case.

Comment: yes that is correct too, maybe my recursive algorithm is not correct and doesn't have a terminating case...

Answer (score 3):

If you run out of memory then you will get an [OutOfMemory exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`System.OutOfMemoryException`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexcetion.aspx

Also as @SLaks indicated a `StackoverflowException` never happens due to running out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you have to reporting "low RAM" is the [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx), but that is only when enough contiguous RAM cannot be allocated for the next operation. It doesn't mean that the host is low on ram.

StackOverflowException may contain this as an inner exception, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If your tree is deep, why don't you manage your own stack instead of using recursion? Something like:

```
Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
stack.Push(rootNode);
Node currentNode;
while( (currentNode = stack.Pop()) != null)
{
    foreach(var childNode in currentNode.Children)
    {
        stack.Push(childNode);
    }
    //process this node.
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that..Thanks I will stare at your example to learn and use it.

Comment: You can change to breadth-first traversal by switching to a `Queue<Node>` instead of a `Stack<Node>` (and using Queue and Dequeue in place of Push and Pop)

Answer (score 1):

I ran myself a little recursive experiement, which gave me around 87000 iterations before running out of stack space. Method calls always use the stack as opposed to the heap. If there is a way to create a heap based stack, then you might get away with a bit more. In that respect, read the following article (although it may not apply in C#!):

[recursion using only heap area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807131/recursion-using-only-heap-area)

Also, check this out...

http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/explanation-of-stack-heap-and-recursion-causing-stack-overflow/

Edit. In answer to your question...

Generally the case is that if your application tries to exceed the stack space you will get a StackOverflowException. If your application tries to exceed the heap space, you will get an OutOfMemoryException