# Easiest way to get rid of 'yield' in (by converting to a state machine) a recursive generator method?

Tags: c#, state-machine, yield-return

I have a nice, elegant (IMO) piece of code I've written that I want to port to other languages, like C++, Java, etc.

The problem I'm facing is twofold:

- The code uses `yield`
- The code is highly recursive

Getting rid of `yield` by hand is *possible*, but *very tedious* -- the process is very mechanical and obviously automatable.
At the same time, the state machine that the C# compiler translates this into is *very ugly* -- it's practically unusable for porting. (I've tried decompiling it; it's just unreadable.)

I'm wondering, do I have any other options than just spending days on this to get rid of `yield` by hand?
Or is there some kind of tool that can convert `yield` blocks to (readable) state machines, which I can then port over like normal code?

---

In case you're curious what I mean by "highly recursive" -- the code below is basically the structure of the code (the actual thing is only ~66 lines; it's not a terribly long function):

```
static IEnumerable<ReturnType> MyRecursiveYielder(args)
{
    if (blah1) yield return foo;
    else if (blah2)
        foreach (var foo1 in foo2.Blah())
            foreach (var item in MyRecursiveYielder(moreArgs))
                yield return item;
    else
    {
        var state = new State();
        foreach (var item in blah)
            foreach (var item2 in MyRecursiveYielder(otherArgs))
                foreach (var item3 in blah3)
                {
                    foreach (var result in MyRecursiveYielder(yetMoreArgs)))
                        yield return result;
                    foobar1();
                }
        while (condition)
            foreach (var foo in blah)
                foreach (var result in MyRecursiveYielder(argh)))
                {
                    if (condition2)
                        foreach (var result in MyRecursiveYielder(almostThere)))
                            yield return result;
                    foobar2();
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oof. Object creation mayhem. You might be better off managing your own stack here instead of going recursive. Here's an answer I posted elsewhere to show what i mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908570/what-excption-do-we-get-upon-low-ram-in-memory/11908770#11908770

Comment: Do you need it to run on demand or can it run in advance? The obvious solution to my mind would be to just stick these in a list every time you do a yield and then return that. Of course then its all in memory whcih looking at the number of things your are looping through might be quite big... Otherwise the big unwieldy statemachine sounds like it might be the solution. In what way is the decompiled state machine unreadable out of interest? Is it just a case of it needs cleaning up so a different decompiler might make it look nicer or is it the structure itself that is a bad thing?

Comment: @Chris: It's better if I can run it on-demand, lazily -- I have no idea how big the output is (it could be anything from zero to, well, an unbounded number of items)... so I can't always just stick the results in a list (although sometimes I can). It's an option though, if all else fails. And regarding the unreadability -- it's 568 lines when I decompile it, with lots of `<>g__initLocal24`-like identifiers and such. And goto's, of course. The entire reason why I wrote it like this was that it was short & elegant... which is why I'm now kind of stuck... :\

Comment: @spender: Haha yeah... the trouble is, turning a normal recursive function into an iterative function is not *quite* as bad as turning a recursive *generator* into an iterative *state machine*, though... just *thinking* about how I'd do it gives me a headache! (But as far as I've been able to see, I don't have a better solution...)

Comment: [Raymond's series on C#'s iterator implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/12/8849519.aspx) might be of interest. And [Jon's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. Been thinking about this for a while. Maybe you could replace the yield returns with a callback call. You could hand in an interface in Java and call a known method. The behaviour is going to be slightly different (i.e. it's more push than pull), but at least it remains lazy.

Comment: @spender: Yeah I was thinking about that too. The trouble is that it could cause... well, a Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution: I can use LINQ, for the most part. That way I wouldn't need to `yield` anything in the first few cases, because those cases aren't stateful.

The stateful yield -- i.e. the last one -- is the problem -- but after sleeping on it, I realized that my "stateful" `yield` code is basically just tree search (breadth-first search, to be exact). Basically like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2011/03/21/recursively-traversing-ienumerable-lt-t-gt.aspx) code.

So I could simply make my own `IEnumerable<T>` class which performs breadth-first search -- i.e., given a transfer function `(T parenet) => (IEnumerable<T> children)`, it would output the children one-by-one, and keep on searching until none is left.

If that works, that would get rid of *all* of the `yield`s, while keeping the code structure essentially the same -- making it a lot more readable and easier to port.

Comment: This makes little sense, Linq is far less portable than yield.  Not in the least because Linq uses yield very heavily.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's what I thought at first too, but there are two counterpoints: (1) C++, at least, has Boost.Range and [P-Stade Oven](http://p-stade.sourceforge.net/oven/doc/html/index.html), and (2) It's a lot *easier* to port LINQ classes which don't exist, than it is to make sense of an iterative version of this code. Nevertheless, I haven't done this yet, and I might still run into issues I'm not foreseeing. :\

Answer (score 1):

What yield accomplishes is close to co-routines. You should be able to port to a language that supports those. Unfortunately, very few languages do. I believe Ada has them.

Next step is fibers. The Win32 API exposes fibers, so for C++ that could be an option. Not for Java I think.

So, short answer: investigate the availability of co-routines or fibers for your target platforms.

Comment: Not an ideal solution but sounds better than what I was going to try, thanks. +1